# How can I get emailjs to return a success message?

Tags: javascript, email, dom-events

I am looking to return a success message once I successfully or unsuccessfully send an email. I have the emails sending ok from the contact form but I would like to display a message on screen to show the message was sent successfully.

Here is my current .js file

```html
function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "minderfinder", {
        "from_name": contactForm.name.value,
        "from_email": contactForm.emailaddress.value,
        "booking_request": contactForm.booking_request.value,
        "mobile": contactForm.mobile.value,
        "date": contactForm.date.value,
        "time": contactForm.time.value
    })
    .then(
        function(response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.status, response.text);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("FAILED", error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something ... But, why not just replace "console.log" with "alert".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried alert instead of console.log and it doesnt produce a message.

Comment: What does the browser's 'console' show? Any errors / warnings?

Comment: I have no errors showing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with the code snippet you posted!
Although,

```html
function sendMail(contactForm) {
    emailjs.send("gmail", "minderfinder", {
        "from_name": contactForm.name.value,
        "from_email": contactForm.emailaddress.value,
        "booking_request": contactForm.booking_request.value,
        "mobile": contactForm.mobile.value,
        "date": contactForm.date.value,
        "time": contactForm.time.value
    })
    .then(
        function(response) {
            //console.log("SUCCESS. status=%d, text=%s", response.status, response.text);
            alert("Email sent successfully!");
        },
        function(error) {
            //console.log("FAILED", error);
            alert("FAILED!"+error);
        }
    );
}
```

This should resolve your issues with not being able to show the message to users!

**console.log()** is only visible when debugging is active and it is only meant for development/debugging purposes.